# How to set correct mount permissions of Minikube grafana pod

Tags: kubernetes, grafana, persistent-volumes

I have a minikube cluster with a grafana pod running in it.

I have mounted a directory for grafana to use as a persistant volume to store.
`minikube mount /var/tmp/minikube-folder1:/folder1`

I receive the output

```
  Mounting host path /var/tmp/minikube-folder1 into VM as /folder1 ...
    ▪ Mount type:   9p
    ▪ User ID:      docker
    ▪ Group ID:     docker
    ▪ Version:      9p2000.L
    ▪ Message Size: 262144
    ▪ Options:      map[]
    ▪ Bind Address: 127.0.0.1:64221
  Userspace file server: ufs starting
✅  Successfully mounted /var/tmp/minikube-folder1 to /folder1
```

i bind to the folder as such in my grafana yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: pvc-grafana
spec:
  volumeName: grafana-pv
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: grafana-pv
spec:
  storageClassName: standard
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  capacity:
    storage: 2Gi
  hostPath:
    path: /folder1
```

and eventually mount it on my container as such

```
   [spec..tempalate..spec above]

    containers:
      - name: mygrafana
        image: grafana/grafana
        ports:
          - containerPort: 3000 
        volumeMounts:
          - name: grafana-storage
            mountPath: /var/lib/grafana

     volumes:
       - name: grafana-storage
         persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: pvc-grafana
```

my grafana pod cant launch and always complains the permissions arent correct on `/var/lib/grafana`

I can remedy it by manually going into `/var/tmp/minikube-folder1/` and `chmod 777`ing the folders each time a new one appears (ex /var/lib/grafana/alerting), but this seems like an inefficient and wrong strategy.

Is there someway to not have the minikube setup have these filesystem permission conflicts?

Answer (score 0):

You have multiples solutions

#### 1 - Set a uid and gid when creating the mount

This imply knowing the uid and gid of the user running inside your pod. To get it you could do something like this :

```shell
$ kubectl run -ti debug --image grafana/grafana --command bash
If you don't see a command prompt, try pressing enter.
debug:/usr/share/grafana$ id
uid=472(grafana) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
```

Then when creating the mount with minikube, set the uid and gid

```shell
$ minikube mount /var/tmp/minikube-folder1:/folder1 --uid 472 --gid 0
```

Now in your pod you can see that the `/var/lib/grafana/` permissions are correct

```shell
grafana-57d4899dd7-fsp5z:/usr/share/grafana$ id
uid=472(grafana) gid=0(root) groups=0(root),47
grafana-57d4899dd7-fsp5z:/usr/share/grafana$ ls -lnd /var/lib/grafana/
drwxrwxr-x    1 472      0             4096 Aug 11 14:19 /var/lib/grafana/
```

#### 2 - Use a security context to run the pod

Localy your folder is created with your user, you can tell your pod to use the same uid as your local user.

First you need to get the uid of the user who created `/var/tmp/minikube-folder1`

```shell
$ ls -lnd /var/tmp/minikube-folder1
total 4
drwxrwxr-x 2 1000 1000 4096 août  11 16:06 /var/tmp/minikube-folder1
```

Let say the uid is 1000.

In your deployment configuration (grafana yaml), you can set the `runAsUser` directive :

```yaml
...
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      securityContext:
        runAsUser: 1000
      containers: 
...
```

Now if you check in your started pod you can see that it's started with uid 1000

```shell
$ kc exec -ti grafana-7c895564cc-w26p6 -- bash
grafana-7c895564cc-w26p6:/usr/share/grafana$ id
uid=1000 gid=0(root) groups=0(root),472
```

And that's the same user as the `/var/lib/grafana/` folder in the pod :

```shell
grafana-5f75d8ff65-dhbb5:/usr/share/grafana$ ls -lnd /var/lib/grafana/
drwxrwxr-x    1 1000     999           4096 Aug 11 14:16 /var/lib/grafana/
```

Hope this is clear and that it helps !